# Testng - Configuration Failures

Tags: selenium, testng

Getting a Configuration failures while running my script from command line at a point where my code calls function from another class.

I am using Eclipse Neon 2, Selenium Webdriver and Testng.

My script works fine when I execute it from eclipse.It also works fine when I remove those function calls and add the respective code in that same class while command line execution, but it fails with those function calls when I try to execute the script from command line or .bat file.

Below my project structure looks like;

I have 3 different classes in a package

```
Testing
  Survey
   selection (package)
     -Class Variable_cfg (this is to define different variables)
     -Class Reuse_fuctions (I am adding all re-useable functions like send_email into this)
     -Class Main_test (this is main test, I will have many like this in future)
```

---

```
public class Variable_cfg()
{
    public static void variables() {....}
}

public class Reuse_functions()
{
      public static void sendMail() {...}
      public static String generateRandomChars() throws IOException {}
      public static void clickScreenshot(String filename, WebDriver driver) throws IOException {}
      public static void startDeleting() throws IOException {}
}

public class Main_test()
{
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeTest
    public void openbrowser(String browser) throws IOException {}

    @DataProvider(name = "runtimeparams")
    @BeforeTest
    public Object[][] createData1() {}

    @Test(priority=1,groups={"Chrome","Firefox","IE"},dataProvider="runtimeparams")
    public void runtest(String env) throws IOException {

        //here I am calling functions from Reuse_Functions class like 
        selection.Reuse_functions.generateRandomChars()...}

    @AfterMethod
    public void exittest(ITestResult result){
        //here I am calling functions from Reuse_Functions class like 
        selection.Reuse_functions.sendMail()
    }
```

if you could help me finding out the solution. Thank you!

Below is my NIA_Main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" >

  <test name="Test01"> 
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
    <classes>
        <class name="selection.Main_test" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

and my bat file looks like

```
set ProjectPath=C:\Users\*******\workspace\Testing
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\NIA_Main.xml
```

I am trying to create a bat file because I want to give to other functional QAs to execute. Otherwise I am running it through command line where I do set projectath and classpath variables before executing it.

Comment: What are the commands you're trying? What is the error you get?

Comment: It just fails with Configuration Failures : 1 on command prompt. No error msg or stack.

Comment: What's your command? e.g. `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml ` or with maven `mvn test` etc...

Comment: java -Denv=QA org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\NIA_Main.xml  ----adding a runtime parameter for environment.

Comment: `-Denv=QA` is Maven style and you execute `java`... Beides there can be some dependencies missing.

Comment: oh..my bad. I have removed it and executing only with java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\NIA_Main.xml

Comment: I assume you have an environment variable for `projectpath` or that you're setting it in a batch? Please elaborate in your question and add the batch your using and possibly the xml for TestNG.

Comment: Yes, setting up the projectpath and classpath before executing it using org.testng.TestNG through command line or added in bat file. Added the xml file and bat file in the main question.

Comment: Don't mix `@DataProvider` and `@BeforeTest` on the same method.

Comment: Could you activate traces (`-verbose 10`) and share the output?

Comment: ( -verbose 10) has helped me to diagnose the issue. It was not actually failing at the function call, but unable to find couple jars in the library. As I directly have added the jars to project buildpath, and were missing from the lib folder. Hence the script was executing fine from eclipse, but giving me issues while executing it through command line as I was giving the path to the lib folder which was missing jars.

Comment: with just "Configuration Failures : 1", it was not helping at all. Thank you juherr for the verbose option, I was not aware of that.